# Como compactar um arquivo em bzip2 pelo PHP

Tags: php

Olá,

Preciso compactar arquivos pelo PHP, e salvá-los em uma pasta, procurei na web, mas só achei como compactar uma string.

Por exemplo: Ao o usuário acessar a URL `x.php?arquivo=exemplo.jpg` o PHP vai compactar o arquivo `exemplo.jpg` já existente no servidor, e vai salvar na pasta `compactados`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No php.net tem exemplos de como compactar com a extensão [zip](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/zip.examples.php) e [bzip2](http://php.net/manual/en/bzip2.examples.php).
No link anterior do bzip2, o exemplo compacta uma string. Então você pode ler o arquivo como string. Segue exemplo do [php.net](http://www.php.net/) adaptado a sua situação:

```
<?php

$filename = "./testfile.bz2";

// open file for writing
$bz = bzopen($filename, "w");

// write string to file
//Aqui você coloca o caminho para o seu arquivo, para ser lido pelo file_get_contents
bzwrite($bz, file_get_contents('./team-member.jpg'));

// close file
bzclose($bz);

// open file for reading
$bz = bzopen($filename, "r");

// read 10 characters
echo bzread($bz, 10);

// output until end of the file (or the next 1024 char) and close it.  
echo bzread($bz);

bzclose($bz);

?>
```

Você também pode compactar em zip usando o primeiro exemplo, também do php.net.

Comment: Valeu mano! Procurei no php.net mas não achei :P